# On page load open a href section by default using javascript

Tags: javascript, href, location-href

I have two navigations and i want the browser to load `#informals-1` by default on page load. How can I do that using javascript? I have a code to navigate between the `-nav` and `-subnav`, but the `#informals-1` section is not activated by default. I have to click on the `informals-1` anchor to get the `subnav` under it.

Before activation - [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrSxo.jpg)
After activation - [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7TxK.jpg)

```
<nav id="documentation-nav">
<ul>

    <li><a href="#informals-1" title="Informal Events" data-rel="informals"><span>1</span>Informals</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#current" title="Technical Events" data-rel="techevents"><span>2</span>Tech Events</a></li>    
</ul>
    </nav>
<nav id="documentation-subnav">
<ul id="informals">
    <li><a href="#informals-1" >Tic Toc</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-2" >Jack of all Trades</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-3" >Tattoo making</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-4" >Face painting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-5" >Foosball</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-6" >Solo Impromptu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-7" >Challenge accepted</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-8" >Sack Race</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-9" >Connected</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-10" >Mystery date</a></li>
    <li><a href="#informals-11" >The 90's Game</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="techevents">
    <li><a href= "#current" title="name1">name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tech-2" title="name2">name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tech-3" title="name3">name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tech-4" title="name4">name1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tech-5" title="name5">name1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you mean with `load` and `open` ? do you want a new window?

Comment: Another _read ma mind_ question.

Comment: i mean, by loading the page, i want the browser to focus on that particular anchor by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following.

Give the li an id

```
<li id="yourId"><a href="#informals-1" >Tic Toc</a></li>
```

then have the window scroll to 500 pixels from top. Change 500 to whatever amount is correct for you.

```
document.getElementById('yourId').style.display = 'block';
window.scrollTo(0, 500);
```